# Unit tests failing after updating lombok version

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, lombok

I have a Java project for which I updated the `org.projectlombok` version to `1.18.22`.
However, my tests started failing with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer$3
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

The mockito version I use is `1.10.19`

This is part of the test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserPreferenceResourceTest {

    private static final String SAMPLE_USER_ID = "userId";
    private UserInsightsResource userInsightsResource;

    @Mock
    private UserPreferenceDao userPreferenceDao;

    @Mock
    private UserEngagementDao userEngagementDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn200IfAllOkay() {
        when(userPreferenceDao.findPrefrenceByUser(SAMPLE_USER_ID)).thenReturn(...);
        when(userEngagementDao.findEngagementByUser(SAMPLE_USER_ID)).thenReturn(...}
```

Is there a chance that the annotations are failing

Any suggestions how to fix this are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe share the source of the test class in question?

Comment: Does UserPreferenceDao or UserPreferenceDao use Lombok annotations? Then their source code would be interesting aswell.

Comment: Another interesting piece of information would be to know which version of Lombok you used before which it still worked. And did you try to go back? Does it still pass? Maybe you introduced another change unnoticedly?

Comment: @ValerijDobler UserPreferenceDao uses jdbi annotations, I'm not sure if they depend on lombok.
Prior to the change, the lombok version was 1.16.4 and the Maven build complained about lombok.

Comment: Maybe go back and fix those complains then, if they are in your source or update involved dependencies? Deprecations are hints for possible future incompatibilities.

Comment: We decided not to update the dependencies. The Maven built was failing due to upgrade of the Maven version on CircleCI.
Once we rolled back the version the issue was fixed.
Thank you for your help!